# .NET multipart data appeared in preamble section

Tags: c#, .net, multipartform-data, dotnet-httpclient

client side is using MultipartFormDataContent with two part of data, one is a file, the other one is some metadata.
In each 3 request, there will be 2 request failed due to FileData empty.

Client:

```
var client = new HttpClient(new WebRequestHandler());
using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent())
{
    var guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    var tmpFileName = string.Format("{0}{1}", guid, Path.GetExtension(fileName));
    var dataContent = new ByteArrayContent(data);
    content.Add(dataContent, guid, tmpFileName);
    var optionContent = new ByteArrayContent(optionData);
    optionContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("parameter") { Name = "optionsStr" };
    content.Add(optionContent);
    var response = client.PostAsync("http://test.com", content).Result;
}
```

Server:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> UploadDocument(string dataStr)
{
    string rootPath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Documents");
    MultipartFormDataStreamProvider provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(rootPath);
    await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);
    if (provider.FileData == null || provider.FileData.Count == 0)
        throw new Exception("There is no file in the current request of httpcontext.");
}
```

After sniffing using Wiresharks, found out the actual file data was misplaced in the preamble section of the multi-part structure:

error request:

[wireshark snapshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQL0J.png)

correct request:

[wireshark snapshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6eq1Z.png)

any clue what may cause such behavior?